# ASP.NET jQuery ajax only works when debugging browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

**Question**:
Why does an ajax call through jQuery, to an ASP.NET API controller, only work when I'm stepping through the javascript on the browser?

**Details**:
I'm developing using MS Visual Studio Express 2013 for the Web, on a Win7 machine, with Firefox as the browser. My project is a mix of MVC and API controllers (in two different controller classes).

My view makes an ajax POST call via jQuery to an API controller in the same project. When building the project, there are no errors. The debugger console in the browser shows no javascript errors.
The GET ajax call works just fine. However, the POST ajax call seems to call "/api/" instead of "/api/BacklogAPI". I get a page that displays:

*Server Error in '/' Application.

The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.*

*Requested URL: /api/*

*Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34237*

This does not happen if I step through the javascript with a debugger. I can't figure out why.

**Tested Already**:
A breakpoint on the API controller POST action verifies that it isn't called during normal usage (although it should be).
Debugging the javascript, with a breakpoint in my ajax call, verifies that the url for the POST call is "/api/BacklogAPI". This is correct. As I step through the rest of the javascript, now my breakpoint on my API controller is hit. Why is it only doing this when I'm debugging?
I've tried restarting the project and browser, with no changes.

**Code**:
Here is the code for the controller (I can disclose business logic or model classes if needed for clarification... this is a personal learning project):

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net;
using WebApplication1.Models.WorkOrder;
using System.Linq;
namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class BacklogAPIController : ApiController
    {
        private WOHolder holder = WOHolder.Current;

        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<WorkOrder> GetAllWO()
        {
            return holder.GetAll();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public WorkOrder GetWO(int id)
        {
            return holder.Get(id);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage AddWO(WorkOrder item)
        {
            holder.Add(item);
            var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Created);
            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

And for the view:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_BacklogBasic.cshtml";
}
@section Scripts {
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
}
@section Header {
    Backlog Tester
}
@section Body {
    <form id="formInput" action="api/" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
        Name: <input name="name" type="text" />
        <br />SN: <input name="serialNumber" type="text" />
        <br />Model: <input name="model" type="text" />
        <br /><input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
    <div id="divOutput"></div>
    <script>
        var uri = "/api/BacklogAPI";
        ShowAll();
        function ShowAll() {
            $.ajax({
                url: uri,
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json"
            })
            .success(function (data) {
                var items = "";
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    items += data[i].name;
                    items += "<br />";
                }
                $("#divOutput").html(items);
            });
        }
        function PostForm(postInfo) {
            $.ajax({
                url: uri,
                type: "POST",
                data: postInfo
            })
            .success(function () {
                ShowAll();
            });
        }
        $("#formInput").submit(function () {
            PostForm($("#formInput").serialize());
        });
    </script>
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cancel the form submission

```
$("#formInput").submit(function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
```

Comment: yep, that was it... also explains the /api/ call, i looked over that. thank you!